# Can't get the same results using Fultext "Like" in SQL statement

Tags: mysql

In the table there are 912 rows. There are a total of 723 rows that have "MFG" in the column I am trying to search.

If I use like: column_name LIKE 'MFG' - I get the 723 results.

If I use fulltext, I get zero.

BUT, I can retrieve any of the other values in the same column, which just shows what I know, the column is set up correct as fulltext.

I checked the stopwords and didn't didn't find MFG in there.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

How can I get the same results using fulltext.

Edit: Query I am using

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(keywords, product, type) AGAINST ('MFG')
```

Gets zeros results but

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE type LIKE 'MFG'
```

Gets 723 results.

Comment: whats the query you are using for fulltext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fulltext does not work on any word which is present in more than 50% of the records.  See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/fulltext-natural-language.html) at the bottom.

Comment: That makes sense, wallyk. Is there a way to overcome this.?

Comment: Answer to my question - use "IN BOOLEAN MODE"

Thank you, wallyk